# tag validation in XSD File

Tags: html, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Someone knows, how to implement the following validate in the XSD file:

When the tag TIPO has the value SER, it is mandatory to register the tag DETALLES_SERVICIOS otherwise if the value is EQU, it is optional

I am using the XSD version 1.0 and I can not implement a way to do this validation.

Thanks in advance for the help.

XML

```html
<REQUERIMIENTO>
 <DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
  <ID_PLAN>BP-7138</ID_PLAN>
  <ID_SUBPRODUCTO>AUT</ID_SUBPRODUCTO>
  <CANTIDAD>1</CANTIDAD>
  <TIPO>SER</TIPO>
  <DETALLES_SERVICIOS>
   <NOMBRE_USUARIO>JANIO</NOMBRE_USUARIO>
   <NUMERO_SERIE>12345</NUMERO_SERIE>
   <IN_BODEGA>130</IN_BODEGA>
  </DETALLES_SERVICIOS>
 </DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
 <DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
  <ID_PLAN>0</ID_PLAN>
  <ID_SUBPRODUCTO>SAMSUNG A510 G</ID_SUBPRODUCTO>
  <CANTIDAD>1</CANTIDAD>
  <TIPO>EQU</TIPO>
 </DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
</REQUERIMIENTO>
```

XSD

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="REQUERIMIENTO">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DETALLES_SOLICITUDES">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID_PLAN" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ID_SUBPRODUCTO" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="CANTIDAD" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="TIPO">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="SER"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EQU"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DETALLES_SERVICIOS">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="NOMBRE_USUARIO" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="NUMERO_SERIE" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                    <xs:element name="IN_BODEGA" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement this in XSD-1.0, but if you find a way to use XSD-1.1, you can use the following `xs:assert` expression after your second `xs:sequence` element:

```
<xs:assert test="((TIPO = 'SER') and DETALLES_SERVICIOS) or (TIPO='EQU')" />
```

EDIT: thx to @MichaelKay to make sure that it isn't possible at all.

Comment: More precisely, there is no way to achieve this in XSD 1.0.